# Parsing a text file with different delimiters which contains nnumeric values

Tags: parsing

I have a text file which read: 
config<001>25
23<220>12
.....

how can i parse so that i need only the values config,001(to be converted into integer after extracting using strtok or any ohter methods please suggest), and 25(to be converted into integer) seperately. i tries strtok its not working as the way i need. Please help me.

Comment: My answer presumes you are using C# as you haven't specified a language

Answer (score 0):

Use [LINQ 2 SQL to import the file](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article706-how-to-read-csv-file-and-import-its-data-with-linq-.aspx) on the delimiters and then use something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com) to do the mapping of fields to say specific objects with specific types.

I did this exact thing in another project and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the mention of `strtok` I'm guessing that you're using C or C++. If you're using C++, I'd probably handle this by creating a ctype facet that treats `<` and `>` as white space, which will make the parsing trivial (`infile >> string >> number1 >> number2;`).

If you're using C, you can use the scan-set conversion with scanf, something like: `sscanf(line, "%[^<] %d> %d", string, &number1, &number2);`